# Ruby CSV.each in while loop not executing second time through

Tags: ruby

I'm working on the [EventReporter](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/event_reporter.html) project to help learn Ruby.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
require 'CSV'

puts 'Welcome to Event Reporter!'
print 'Enter command: '
command = gets.chomp

def clean(attribute, type)
    if (type == 'regdate')
    elsif (type == 'first_name')
    elsif (type == 'last_name')
    elsif (type == 'email_address')
    elsif (type == 'homephone')
        homephone = attribute
        homephone = homephone.to_s.gsub(/\D/, '')
        if (homephone.length < 10)
            homephone = '0000000000'
        elsif (homephone.length == 11)
            if (homephone[0] == '1')
                homephone[0] = ''
            else
                homephone = '0000000000'
            end
        elsif (homephone.length > 11)
            homephone = '0000000000'
        end
        return homephone
    elsif (type == 'street')
    elsif (type == 'city')
    elsif (type == 'state')
    elsif (type == 'zipcode')
        zipcode = attribute.to_s.rjust(5, "0")[0..4]
        return zipcode
    end
    return attribute
end

queue = []
while (command != 'q') do
    command = command.split
    if (command[0] == 'load')
        command[1] ? filename = command[1] : filename = 'event_attendees.csv'
        attendees = CSV.open filename, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol
        puts "Loaded #{filename}"
    elsif (command[0] == 'find')
        attribute = command[1]
        criteria = command[2]

        # REACHES HERE SECOND TIME AROUND
        puts "#{command[0]} #{command[1]} #{command[2]}"

        attendees.each do |attendee|
            # ISNT REACHING HERE SECOND TIME AROUND
            puts 'TEST'

            # get cleaned attendee attribute
            attendee_attribute = clean(attendee[attribute.to_sym], attribute)
            # see if it matches the criteria input
            if criteria.to_s.downcase.strip == attendee_attribute.to_s.downcase.strip
                # if it does, add the attendee to the queue
                puts 'Match!'
                queue << attendee
            end
        end
    end
    print 'Enter command: '
    command = gets.chomp
end
```

It seems that the `attendees.each` isn't being executed the second time through the while loop. Why is this?

```
~/practice/event_manager >>  ruby 'lib/event_reporter.rb'
Welcome to Event Reporter!
Enter command: load
Loaded event_attendees.csv
Enter command: find zipcode 11111
find zipcode 11111
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
Enter command: find zipcode 11111
find zipcode 11111
Enter command: q
~/practice/event_manager >>
```

Comment: I think once it reads through the CSV instance the first time you will have to call `.rewind` on it to reset it back to the start of the file. Try `attendees.rewind` *after* the `attendees.each do ... end`.

Comment: Ahhh ok that works now and makes sense. Thanks! Could you please write that up as an answer for future people to reference?

Comment: Added as an answer per your request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html), the CSV object behaves basically like a regular IO object. They keep track of their current position in the file which is advanced by reading through it, generally line by line. So on your first `attendees.each`, you read through the entire file. Subsequent calls to `.each` will try to read the next line, but there is not any since we are already at the end of the file hence your loop does not execute anymore.

You can fix this by rewinding the underlying IO instance to the beginning of the file, using [#rewind](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-rewind). In your specific case, put it after iterating through the attendees.

```
attendees.each do |attendee|
  # ...
end
attendees.rewind
```