# Strange behavior using CSV class

Tags: ruby

Here's the situation. Need to generate the `report` only if the `index` is last. Which is why I have `csvsize = []; contents.each{|x| csvsize<<x }; @csvsize = (csvsize.size-1)`.

The problem is that `each_with_index` block will not fire as shown here.  **EXAMPLE 1**

```
contents = CSV.open "event_attendees.csv", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol
csvsize = []; contents.each{|x| csvsize<<x }; @csvsize = (csvsize.size-1)

contents.each_with_index do |row, index|

  id    = row[:_]
  name  = row[:first_name].downcase.split.map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
  phone = clean_phone(row[:homephone])

      # . . .

  # Generate report from ERB template
  report = ERB.new(File.read 'templates/reports.erb').result(binding)
  save_to_template({id: 1, directory: 'reports', file: 'report', data: report}) if index == @csvsize
end
```

It will fire **only** if I reassign `contents` like this: **EXAMPLE 2**

```
contents = CSV.open "event_attendees.csv", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol
csvsize = []; contents.each{|x| csvsize<<x }; @csvsize = (csvsize.size-1)

contents = CSV.open "event_attendees.csv", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol
contents.each_with_index do |row, index|

  id    = row[:_]
  name  = row[:first_name].downcase.split.map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
  phone = clean_phone(row[:homephone])

      # . . .

  # Generate report from ERB template
  report = ERB.new(File.read 'templates/reports.erb').result(binding)
  save_to_template({id: 1, directory: 'reports', file: 'report', data: report}) if index == @csvsize
end
```

Why does the CSV object stored in `contents` need to be reassigned? It seems strange that I have to do `contents = CSV.open "event_attendees.csv", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol` twice just because I want to get it's `size` before running the second block.

Can someone explain why or how `contents` is losing scope/assignment after the first block in the above example 1?

Comment: Read my answer to a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602313/ruby-csv-each-in-while-loop-not-executing-second-time-through/23602746#23602746). Basically, the `contents` is an IO object which you read all the way through to the end. You have to use `rewind` to reset it. After your `.each` loop.

Comment: As pointed out by Daniël above, `CSV.each {}` iterates over the lines of the CSV file, and thus it makes sense that contents is empty if you don't reset it.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Thank you for that information. I will read up on that.

Comment: `contents.rewind.each_with_index do |row, index|` shouldn't this work then? Because I'm getting: *undefined method `each_with_index' for 0:Fixnum*

Comment: Apparently it doesn't like to be chained. As `contents.rewind;

contents.each_with_index do |row, index|` works fine.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Thanks for the info. If you post as an answer I will accept.

Comment: @feed_me_code It's a bit silly to post the exact same answer twice to be honest. Maybe it's better to just remove this question now that it is solved. If you want to thank me you can just upvote the answer in the other question's thread ;)